# How do i use a variable from shell script in postgres sql column alias with double quotes

Tags: postgresql, shell

In the below query I am not able to replace the variable :v7.
Please help me resolve this.

```
select
(case when donor='1' then 'ABC' when donor='2' then 'DEF' when donor='3' then 'GHI' else 'OTHER' END) as "MSP",
'DP' as "Role",
'Service' as "Transaction",
current_date as "Date",
coalesce(sum(case when c.data='1' then cnt end),0) as "Total Count",
coalesce(sum(case when c.data='2' then cnt end),0) as "Counta in :v7 or less",
coalesce(sum(case when c.data='3' then cnt end),0) as "Counta delivered in >:v7",
coalesce(round(sum(case when c.data='2' then cnt end)/sum(case when c.data='1' then cnt end)*100,2),0)||'%' as "Service Level"
from
(
select '1' as data,count(*) as cnt,donor from tbl_portorder a, tbl_portsubscriber b where a.rid=b.npo_rid  and npo_type='NOR' and send_sd_time::date between DATE((:v1)::TEXT) and DATE((:v2)::TEXT) and sd_rsp_time is not null group by 1,3
union all
select '1' as data,count(*) as cnt,donor from tbl_portorder_history a,tbl_portsubscriber_history b where a.rid=b.npo_rid  and npo_type='NOR' and send_sd_time::date between DATE((:v1)::TEXT) and DATE((:v2)::TEXT) and sd_rsp_time is not null group by 1,3
union all
select '2' as data,count(msisdn) as cnt,donor from tbl_portorder a, tbl_portsubscriber b where a.rid=b.npo_rid  and npo_type='NOR' and send_sd_time::date between DATE((:v1)::TEXT) and DATE((:v2)::TEXT) and sd_rsp_time is not null and sd_rsp_time between send_sd_time and send_sd_time+interval :v6 group by 1,3
union all
select '2' as data,count(msisdn) as cnt,donor from tbl_portorder_history a,tbl_portsubscriber_history b where a.rid=b.npo_rid  and npo_type='NOR' and send_sd_time::date between DATE((:v1)::TEXT) and DATE((:v2)::TEXT) and sd_rsp_time is not null and sd_rsp_time between send_sd_time and send_sd_time+interval :v6 group by 1,3
union all
select '3' as data,count(msisdn) as cnt,donor from tbl_portorder a, tbl_portsubscriber b where a.rid=b.npo_rid  and npo_type='NOR' and send_sd_time::date between DATE((:v1)::TEXT) and DATE((:v2)::TEXT) and sd_rsp_time is not null and sd_rsp_time > send_sd_time+interval :v6 group by 1,3
union all
select '3' as data,count(msisdn) as cnt,donor from tbl_portorder_history a,tbl_portsubscriber_history b where a.rid=b.npo_rid  and npo_type='NOR' and send_sd_time::date between DATE((:v1)::TEXT) and DATE((:v2)::TEXT) and sd_rsp_time is not null and sd_rsp_time > send_sd_time+interval :v6 group by 1,3
) c group by 1,2;
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Can't you see that your posting is virtually unreadable? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

The question could be rephrased as: *how to use a psql variable as part of a column name?*

It can be done in two steps:

1. create another variable with `\set` to assemble the other variable with the rest of the contents of the column name. The quoting rules inside psql metacommands are tricky so you need to be careful with spaces and quotes.
2. use this variable as your column alias:

   SELECT [expression] AS :"mycolvar", ...

Example :

```
$ psql -v v7="multi-word string" << EOF
\set colname 'Counta in ' :v7 ' or less'
select 'example' as :"colname";
EOF
```

Result:

```
 Counta in multi-word string or less 
-------------------------------------
 example
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this worked perfectly...!!!

Comment: @AnilKumar: nice! Please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).